# Monitoring ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, monitoring

I have ingestion pipeline source --> ActiveMQ --> Storm --> HDFS.
Now I want to monitor ActiveMQ queue so as to detect failures and send email to concerned person.

I haven't used it before so I'm looking at options that can be used for monitoring these queues.
Can somebody suggest suitable tools ?

Answer (score 0):

See http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq.html. But here you only see information how to access the data.

With the jolokia interface you have a REST api which access all jmx values.

Check for existing monitoring application you already have and let's see if they can do REST requests or jmx. E.g. you could use Graphite, Kibana, monitis.